# How do I tell IntelliJ to start gradle with Java 1.6 JDK?

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, gradle

A simple question I couldn't figure out even after hours of trying and searching:

I have both Java 6 and 7 installed.

**How do I tell IntelliJ to start Gradle builds with a JDK version 1.6?**

No matter what I do, IntelliJ keeps starting my gradle with

```
"c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_10\jre\bin\java" -Dgradle.home=C:\_CODING_\gradle-1.4 [...]
```

I tried:

- all project modules are set to use 1.6
- `JAVA_HOME` is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38`
- setting `IDEA_JDK` did nothing
- `gradle -v` recognizes 1.6 as its JDK on command line
- restarting IntelliJ and/or computer didn't change the behavior

Is there a setting somewhere to avoid Java 1.7 from being invoked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although [Denis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15619311/409349) helped me investigate further it wasn't successful at first.

#### I've got 99 problems but gradle isn't one

My first find was that in fact not gradle is the problem but the whole IDE is using Java 7 despite my settings say otherwise.

I had several issues to fight:

1. Java 7 installed a copy of java.exe in `C:\Windows\System32\` which was picked up earlier in `%PATH%` than the also set `%JAVA_HOME%/bin%`

   => removing the copies led to the desired `%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe` being picked up correctly
2. Next problem was that starting IntelliJ via the `idea64.exe` still used the JDK7 and I could not find a way to change that

   => **Pro tip** in testing that: IDEA Plugin [SystemProperties](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pr=idea&pluginId=15) displays all JAVA-Props currently used by the IDE
   => Use `idea.bat` instead to have a configurable way instead
3. `idea.bat` still refused to use the JDK set in `%JAVA_HOME%` but used the bundled JRE instead ( `%IDEA_HOME%/jre`)

   => Checking the content of the bat-file lead me to the solution to define `%IDEA_JDK%` pointing to `%JAVA_HOME%` which is indeed the only variable the bat checks before resorting to the bundled JRE

#### Final thoughts

There are some weird issues regarding setting the right JDK/JRE for launching IntelliJ but it's perfectly doable without changing any properties-files or launch-files, thus making it safe for upgrading.

#### Bonus tip

If you are using Windows and need a better way to keep track of System Properties I recommed using [RapidEE](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about). It's GUI is wayyy better than the ugly Windows UI which hasn't change since Windows 95.

Comment: Ok then. This thread provides a little bit more insight on IJ under 64-bit jre under windows specifics - http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5482146

Comment: @denis.zhdanov: I just tried the latest IntelliJ, under MacOS, and launching a gradle task from the gradle tool still doesn't use the project's configured SDK. It shouldn't use JAVA_VERSION: there can be only one JAVA_VERSION for 3 different projects opened in the same IntelliJ, and all using a different SDK.

Answer (score 14):

... 2.5 years later:

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 15.0, and I had a similar issue:

This version of IDEA ships bundled with JDK 1.8, and I want to build and run a Gradle project under JDK 1.7

**The JDK used by Gradle is configurable in the preferences** (may not have been the case earlier):

IDEA > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle

... under "Use local gradle distribution" you should see the "Gradle JVM" property.

NOTE: in my case, it only appears to have taken effect after a system reboot. Something to try if it doesn't work right away!

Comment: Thank you!  This is what solved the issue for me.  In my case I didn't have to restart my system or my IntelliJ IDEA (I'm on OS X - IDEA 15.0.6)

Comment: I actually had the opposite problem (Gradle was mysteriously trying to run under 1.7 but I wanted 1.8) and this fixed it for me. Didn't need a restart myself either. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

'jre choose' algorithm is defined [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/gradle/src/org/jetbrains/plugins/gradle/remote/GradleJavaHelper.java), namely, it tries the following:

1. Java location referenced at 'gradle.java.home' system property (if any);
2. 'JAVA_HOME' env variable;
3. Project jdk;
4. Any jdk configured at the ide;

I suspect you have 'gradle.java.home' which points to java 1.7 left at $IDEA_HOME/bin/idea.properties

Comment: Thanks for your tips but as I said in my [own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15635935/409349) the problem lied somewhere else.

Comment: If I specify a project JDK it's because I want to use it. Why else would I set it. Project JDK should definitely be the default.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was: I want to run 1.8, but it was running 1.6.

When I run "gradle run" inside the IntelliJ idea I could see the output:

```
10:50:35: Executing external task 'run'... :compileJava :processResources UP-TO-DATE :classes Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/raig Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.raig     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) :run FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I modified 
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/Info.plist

```
<key>JVMOptions</key>
    <dict>
      <key>ClassPath</key>
      <string>$APP_PACKAGE/Contents/lib/bootstrap.jar:$APP_PACKAGE/Contents/lib/extensions.jar:$APP_PACKAGE/Contents/lib/util.jar:$APP_PACKAGE/Contents/lib/jdom.jar:$APP_PACKAGE/Contents/lib/log4j.jar:$APP_PACKAGE/Contents/lib/trove4j.jar:$APP_PACKAGE/Contents/lib/jna.jar</string>

      <key>JVMVersion</key>
      <string>1.6*,1.7+</string>
```

I added "1.8*", in the JVMVersion key.

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
      <string>1.8*,1.6*,1.7+</string>
```

I restarted the IntelliJ, run the task and I got:

```
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: this fixed my issue but oddly enough on restart my font changed ?!

Answer (score 1):

JUST CHANGE GRADLE PROPERTIES FILE IN YOUR PROJECT TO INCLUDE:

org.gradle.java.home = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home

or whatever JDK u need. I was looking for an answer like a weak, it drove my absolutely crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the response from denis.zhdanov:
Since the age-old problem of Intellij not picking up the system/env variables from bash when invoking it from the "icon click" in Mac OS X - you will have to fine the Info.plist and add the property to the file in order to make it work.  For example:

On your system, find:  */Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 12.app/Contents/Info.plist*

Edit the file to add the  value inside the Properties  section:

`<dict>
        <key>gradle.java.home</key>
 <string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home</string>
      </dict>`

Where the path is your JVM's $JAVA_HOME.