# Choose Gradle JDK in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

My system `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` are pointing to JDK 7, but I want to use JDK 8 in project opened in IntelliJ. I changes settings in Project Structure and it works great in IDE, but unfortunately Gradle build run from IDE still uses JDK 7. How can I specify Gradle JDK in IntelliJ 13.0?

Comment: Good question... No such option in 13.x as far as I can see.

Comment: See to the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15617170/2650174).